# How to generate nested tree of offsets based on index permutation C++

Tags: c++

I got the following offsets which reset and go to the next offset if offset value hits `0xC`. The last offset is always `0xC`.

How do I generate the nested tree of offsets based on index.

The pattern goes like this

```
0,C         = index 0
4,C         = index 1
8,C         = index 2
0,0,C       = index 3
0,4,C       = index 4
0,8,C       = index 5
4,0,C       = index 6
4,4,C       = index 7
4,8,C       = index 8
8,0,C       = index 9
8,4,C       = index 10
8,8,C       = index 11
0,0,0,C     = index 12
```

and so on and so on.

[image]

Comment: The only thing that would makes any kind of sense here are your indexes are wrong. "Index 7" (whatever it means) should be "4,4,C", and "4,8,C" is "index 8" (whatever it means again). Only then there is some kind of a pattern here. If so, to generate it is fairly trivial, if it's done backwards. Drop the "C", then keep taking a modulus by 3, multiply the modulus by 8; lather, rinse, repeat. When done, reverse the results. End of story.

Comment: Can you give me some example code on the % modulus

Comment: You should find plenty examples in your C++ book. You are using a C++ book, right, to learn C++, and this is a sample problem in your book, right? Note that if you start counting indexes, 0, 1, 2..., take the result of modulus by 3, and multiply by 4, you get 0, 4, 8, 0, 4, 8, 0, 4, 8.... The last digit. Pop quiz: what do you think happens if you start counting indexes, divide by 3 (ignoring the remainder), and then try the same trick again? Now, put the whole thing in a loop, and you have your answer.

Comment: I'll post what I got in a answer so far.

Comment: Although this is a good start, the correct answer will not be limited to 4 digits, but will use a vector and a loop to quickly compute the value for any index. In my head, I estimate about 4-5 lines of code to generate the values in reverse order, and then maybe a few lines to reverse the result into natural order. Should work for any index, from 0 to billions. It's the same basic approach that takes any integer, say 247, and gets you '2', '4', and '7' out of it. And it works for any integer, and not just up to 999. Same thing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int offset_0 = 0;
  int offset_1 = 0;
  int offset_2 = 0;
  int offset_3 = 0;
  int offset_4 = 0;

  bool offset_0_activate = true;
  bool offset_1_activate = false;
  bool offset_2_activate = false;
  bool offset_3_activate = false;

  int index = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            offset_0 += 4;

        if (offset_0 == 0xC) {
            offset_0 = 0;
            offset_1 += 4;
        }
        if (offset_1 == 0xC) {
            offset_1 = 0;
            offset_2 += 4;
        }
        if (offset_2 == 0xC) {
            offset_2 = 0;
            offset_3 += 4;
        }
        if (offset_3 == 0xC) {
            break;
        }
        printf("index = %d offset0 = %d offset1 = %d offset2 = %d offset3 = %d\n", i, offset_0, offset_1, offset_2, offset_3);
    }
}
```